# composing a commit message without actually commiting

Tags: git, commit

I would like to have bring up the usual editor for a commit message without actually creating a commit after editing. It should propose a message, filled with the usual `git status` information and a full `git diff`, which are stripped again after editing. The resulting text is intended to be passed to `git commit-tree` later on.

So essentially I look for something like

```
git commit -eF proposed-message.txt -v --cleanup=default
```

that does not create a commit, but instead spits out the commit message to the standard output or leaves it in a file for later use. It there some git subcommand that can help me with this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360867/does-git-allow-me-to-write-my-next-commit-message-gradually-during-developing

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [prepare-commit-msg hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_prepare_commit_msg) to achieve what you want, by copying the commit message file somewhere and then making the commit fail (exit the hook with a nonzero status).  You can run the editor on the file to simulate what git would have done, had the hook not failed (just run `$(git var GIT_EDITOR) "$1"`; see [git-var](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-var.html)).  Of course you will need to turn this action on and off somehow—perhaps via an environment variable, for instance—so that it does not affect normal commits.

As a general rule, though, this sort of trickiness is a bad idea.  See the linked StackOverflow posting in [Jubobs' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31372660/composing-a-commit-message-without-actually-commiting#comment50725064_31372660).